# What does this Error (utf-8) using SentenceTransformer mean?

Tags: python, sentence-similarity

I **had a working code** with the BERT Sentence Transformer for weeks. And out of nowhere it started to produce an error. I reduced my code to the one line, that causes the error:

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
```

The complete errormassage is as follows:

```
runfile('C:/Users/ga2943/Gregor Schweitzer - Masterthesis Adrian/Code/FSzuBR_bert_distil_Multicluster.py', wdir='C:/Users/ga2943/Gregor Schweitzer - Masterthesis Adrian/Code')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\ga2943\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3343, in run_code
    self.showtraceback(running_compiled_code=True)

  File "C:\Users\ga2943\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2026, in showtraceback
    self.showsyntaxerror(filename, running_compiled_code)

  File "C:\Users\ga2943\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2088, in showsyntaxerror
    stb = self.SyntaxTB.structured_traceback(etype, value, elist)

  File "C:\Users\ga2943\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1420, in structured_traceback
    newtext = linecache.getline(value.filename, value.lineno)

  File "C:\Users\ga2943\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\linecache.py", line 16, in getline
    lines = getlines(filename, module_globals)

  File "C:\Users\ga2943\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\linecache.py", line 47, in getlines
    return updatecache(filename, module_globals)

  File "C:\Users\ga2943\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\linecache.py", line 137, in updatecache
    lines = fp.readlines()

  File "C:\Users\ga2943\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 1904: invalid continuation byte
```

Sometimes it produces a different errormassage:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-23-dbcd88385343>", line 1, in <module>
    from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer

  File "C:\Users\ga2943\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sentence_transformers\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .datasets import SentencesDataset, SentenceLabelDataset

  File "C:\Users\ga2943\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sentence_transformers\datasets.py", line 5, in <module>
    from torch.utils.data import Dataset

  File "C:\Users\ga2943\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .sampler import Sampler, SequentialSampler, RandomSampler, SubsetRandomSampler, WeightedRandomSampler, BatchSampler

  File "C:\Users\ga2943\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\sampler.py", line 1, in <module>
    import torch

  File "C:\Users\ga2943\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\__init__.py", line 83, in <module>
    __all__ += [name for name in dir(_C)

NameError: name '_C' is not defined
```

I did **not delete libraries** or anything. Does anyone know how to resolve my error?
What could have happened automatically in the background?

Some additional facts:

1. The same code **does work on colab** - so the library itself is not
   broken.
2. It also stopped working on the computer of a colleague of mine, we are sharing the same folder in which the code is(that is the dir in the err msg)

Comment: can you try some other encoding standards? Like Latin-1?

Comment: @Justice_Lords how would I do that and why would utf-8 suddenly stop working?

Comment: The module can be updated maybe? Maybe create a virtualenv and then install everything in it and run the program.